# My sugar daddy wants personal information to make me a member of "staff" in his company

Tags: scams, sugar-daddy

I met a guy who wanted to be my sugar daddy and we started talking. He’s sweet and we have actual conversations but he wants to make me a member of “staff” in his company and wants my information. I declined to do so and we still talk but then he mentioned it again and I am starting to think he might be a scammer.

Comment: When did young women forget what it means to be a *sugar daddy*, and what being a *sugar baby* entails?

Comment: I own a business. Getting someone on the payroll takes time and effort. If I actually wanted to send goodies to a stranger on the internet, I might start with buying something from their amazon wishlist, or subscribing to their patreon or ko-fi or whatever. These are small things I can stop any time. The risk to both participants is low. When someone wants to **start** with something that is clearly fraudulent, and requires something of value (contact info in this case) from you, you already know they're not doing what they say they're doing. Move on.

Comment: First, when you say you "met" this guy, did you meet him in person, or on the internet?  If the latter, it IS a scam, guaranteed.  If you met him in person... Well, it still might be a scam: a friend of mine met a guy she really liked, they moved in together, and a few months later he cleaned out her bank account and left for parts unknown, taking her jewelry and various other portable items.  Bottom line: don't give him personal information, and make sure any payment from him is cash or check.

Comment: Wow.  They combined two different scams into one mega scam.

Comment: I am stupefied that so many people are falling for this scam given how glaringly obvious it is.

Comment: @KateGregory - Enough to be a great answer. I've sent teachers money, thru DonorChoose, or via their Amazon wish list to help out. Or helped people via GoFundMe. The 'sugar-daddy' thing is out of control. If no one fell for it, it would be over, except for congressmen.

Comment: @JohnFx **we** know it's a scam, because **we** are **old and experienced**.  OP???  She even thinks it's a scam.

Comment: **The 'sugar-daddy' thing is out of control.  If no one fell for it, it would be over, except for congressmen.**   Congressmen have sugar daddies??? ;->)

Comment: @BobBaerker They're called "donors" and "lobbyists" at that level :)

Answer (score 6):

It is a scam. The story is an attempt to get information that can be used to steal money or to launder money, or both.

Even if they are not lying, and they are trying to add you to the company payroll, that brings up other troubling problems. There are tax issues for the pay you would be receiving. There could be issues if the company isn't 100% owned by them, they could get fired for fraud, and the company would be looking to get the money back.

There is no way this ends well.

Answer (score 3):

It is 100% a scam. There is clear language that makes it seem so. Not only does he want to make you a member of his "staff" (using), he also wants your information. That is an immediate red flag and it's good that you caught on, and the issues presented by @mhoran_psprep that could turn up are exactly the consequences you should look out for. It's always good to be wary if someone asks for personal information.